# How do I send a cookie along with my GET request in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I need to send a cookie along with every GET request in VB.NET? I already searched for codes but I can't find something that works for me. Can someone give me a simple code to do this? Thanks! All of your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean under "send cookies"?

Cookies stored in the browser and you can reach them via `Request` object. You can also change cookies putting it to `Response` object.

Here is a lot of examples: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/browsers/cookie-session-vb.aspx

```
//read 
Request.Cookies("MyCookie")

// set
Response.Cookies("MyCookie")("Data") = TextBox1.Text
Response.Cookies("MyCookie")("Time") = DateTime.Now.ToString("G")
Response.Cookies("MyCookie").Expires=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
```

Comment: I have a session id and value, I believe you need to send this along with your every page request that requires authentication, right?

Comment: Can you use built-in asp.net authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx. It works almost in the same way to store token in cookies.

Comment: Anyway\, in your case you need to post authentication cookie to the `Response` object on login action and write `HttpModule` whitch will check this cookie during each request.

Comment: I got confused. Hmmm. To make it simple. How do you set the session id and value to the browser?

Comment: I don't. Asp.net do it for me. And I don't care about what session id now and what data is related to the current session. All this staff is handled by asp.net.

Comment: Check this out to setup simple asp.net application with form authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx